# Why FB like button in my website is showing only for users from US ip address?

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-like

I have added a FB like button to my website last week and i found like button didnt appear in my website.

After lots of troubleshooting, came to know that, like button is showing up only for US ip addtress and its not showing up if an user is browsing from non-us IP address.

**Here is my code**

```
div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<div class="fb-like" data-href="My website link" data-width="The pixel width of the plugin" data-height="The pixel height of the plugin" data-colorscheme="light" data-layout="standard" data-action="like" data-show-faces="true" data-send="false"></div>
```

Comment: Please provide code example and indicate the countries you are referring.

Comment: Please find my question updated with code and the country i am browsing from is India

Comment: Use Firebug to check what is created by the Facebook calls. Verify the HTML injected on the page and compare it. Also, check firebug/browser console log to see if there is any issue. I dont see anything problematic, so it should be working.

Comment: Its working perfectly if we browse the page from an US ip address, But its not working if i browse from India IP address. I am very much sure its working for US ip address

Comment: Well, either your ISP is blocking it or your network is very slow... if you dont look at the code and tell us if something is added there or not we cant help you further.

Comment: Monitored javascript request and response using firebug, just one request is there with 200 response. Request sent to connect.facebook.net. Dont know why other requests are not sent. We are seeing three more request if browsed from US ip adress

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75640/discussion-between-user3677420-and-jorge-ferreira).

Comment: After a quick research, i have found few other website with this same issue. I don't know why they did'nt bring this up to facebook.

Comment: I would run your page in the [Facebook debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/) and see if it's being scraped correctly. This could be an issue with your DNS settings (mis-configured IPv6 records ... etc).